# What is 'dead metal'?

Tags: high-voltage

I just started hearing this term in the context of an arc or sparking between components.  Can anyone define `dead metal`?

Comment: never heard that term used for arcing components unless the dead means diverted ESD or BDV between shielded metal for some protection.   In extrusion it refers to zones of high stress to tooling that result in poor extrusion life on the die from poor symmetry or extrusion ratio. Or it is an underground heavy band or famous British Robot that won in a stage battle.

Comment: I have not heard that term, either.

Comment: Does it have something to do with Ozzy Osbourne?

Comment: One of the house robots in the UK BBC program "Robot Wars"?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, dead metal is metal that should not be live. For example, the metal chassis of an appliance that receives mains voltage inside is dead metal. It may become live if there are faults.

Comment: _"It may become live if there are faults."_ - I propose we call that _zombie metal_ :P

Answer (score 1):

I would add to the answer by @replete above. In the context of arcing or sparking, "dead metal" would be uncharged metal that effectively shortens the gap between two high voltage points by providing a passive conduction route for the discharge.